# HH:MM:SS format won't work, seconds pass over 60

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I have a large table of times but I can't figure out how to convert 60 seconds to 1 minute without modifying all the document. For example I have : 9:56:69 , but I want it to show 9:57:9. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely your "time" is actually a text string that looks like time.  You will need to parse the data and change it to a time, then format it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `9:56:59` in cell `A1`, and that all your values only have hours, minutes, and seconds, you could do this in cell `B1`:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```

Then format `B1` to your desired Time number format, or choose `h:mm:ss` from the Custom list.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "without modifying all [of] the document", since you'll have to make changes somehow.

Also, what was your workflow? How did the data get into Excel? I ask because when I have a blank cell with format `hh:mm:ss`, Excel 2013 automatically converts `11:12:63` into `11:13:03`.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply type "9:56:69" in cell A1, Excel will assume it is a time and will enter the number `0.4146875` which represents the time `9:57:09` and will be displayed as such if you format the cell as "h:mm:ss".

Assuming that "9:56:69" is entered as **Text** (for example by typing `'9:56:69` in cell A1, you can convert it to a time using the `TIMEVALUE` function. Enter the following in cell B1:

```
=TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

and format cell B1 as Time.